# Object detection with MaskRCNN. Why is mean average Precision(maP) equal to 0 when training with Json dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, precision, mask-rcnn

While I was installing the Maskrcnn on Windows10 by following the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QntADriNHuk&t=1177s (286 - Object detection using Mask RCNN: end-to-end from annotation to prediction), every steps look fine until doing the prediction. My model's prediction bounding box is not a rectangle and it is more like a line. The maP is equal to 0.0 no matter I trained model by 3 epoches(like the video) or 25 epoches. It works but it doesn't work like video. Is there anybody who met the same problem as me?

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted the tutorial which you did. I presume the maskrcnn core scripts (model.py etc) are not suitable for tensorflow 2.x

You need to find a suitable version for tensorflow 2.x (original matterpot mrcnn is built for tf 1.x)

Edit:
I found that this version of Mask rcnn will work in tensorflow 2.??

Please download the libraries from `requirments.txt`